# Forbidden error when trying to run update.php MediaWiki maintenance script on WAMP

Tags: php, mediawiki

I recently installed WAMP on Windows and have set up a local MediaWiki installation. After the installation, I tried to to install a new extension. For it to work, I have to run the maintenance script update.php. However, when I go to `localhost/maintenance/update.php`, I'm getting a 403 error.

## Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /maintenance/update.php on this server.

---

*Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80*

How do I fix this? or is there another way to run the maintenance scripts on WAMP (perhaps with a command line)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, it is desired behaviour for the program, since [the .htaccess file for the `/maintenance/` directory](https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/303d9156c2139d900be1a925d92806618311b7e4/maintenance%2F.htaccess) has this:

```
Deny from all
```

This is because the `update.php` file is not meant to be loaded directly from a web browser. [You must read the documentation for MediaWiki updating from a browser](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading#Web_browser) to utilize it correctly. [You can also run it from the command line](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Update.php)

Comment: I changed it to Allow from all and now I am getting a "#!/usr/bin/env php This script must be run from the command line". Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: @dan_N. I just said in the answer that `update.php` is not meant to be loaded directly from a web browser. Follow the documentation links that I provided for you please.

Comment: I just tried to a web upgrade and the installation is hanging.

Comment: @dan_N. More details are needed (PHP errors, perhaps found in the Apache logs), and it's worthy of a separate question once you find those details. Maybe the installation is still working and taking longer than you expect.

Comment: @dan_N: if it's a local installation (localhost), you should be able to just run the script from the command line. Did you give that a try?